# Whitelabel Error Page when openapi is removed

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springfox

I am migrating an application from swagger2.0 to 3.0. When I comment open API I am getting
Whitelabel Error Page. Wanted to understand what is the relationship between these.

```
     // implementation ('org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.2'){
    //      exclude group: 'io.github.classgraph', module: 'classgraph'
   //   }
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'
```

The error in browser

```
The url i trigger: http://localhost:8888/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config#/


Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Aug 12 16:14:07 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Log
12-08-2021 16:16:13.002 [35m[http-nio-8888-exec-5][0;39m [31mWARN [0;39m o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound - No mapping for GET /swagger-ui/index.html

Also, can someone suggest How to configure custom contrext path?

Comment: You're getting a detailed error message on the server console. Post it.

Comment: Try `/swagger-ui` not `/swagger-ui.html`